# Файл заголовка не видит другой файл заголовка. UE4/C++/VisualStudio

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unreal-engine-4

В проекте в каталоге с классами я создал ещё каталог.
Файлы внутри него "не видят" файлы из основного каталога.

Всё ок, если путь к заголовкам указывать абсолютный или относительный при помощи "../", но, предполагаю, это делается иначе, т.к. "**CoreMinimal.h**" в подобном не нуждается.
Расскажите, пожалуйста, что тут, вероятно, не так.

[image: Так располагаются каталоги]

Comment: Все правильно, при использовании синтаксиса `#include "..."` следует указывать путь относительно текущего файла.

Comment: @user7860670, но, если добавить в солюшен пути включаемых файлов, то можно и не писать относительный путь. Не писать ../../../modules/inc/include.h

Comment: @Aptem_f А если добавлять пути в настройки проекта, то не следует использовать синтаксис с кавычками.